# ios video playback using flash builder / flex

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Hi I am trying to create an iphone app that streams a video from a remote server (that automatically creates video files) , I'm using flash builder 4.7, mobile flex.

My expertise with fb / flex is not great but am getting there.

Using StageWebView I have made some progress and can stream a simple mp4 file , however the files I want to stream have the wrong extension so the iphones internal video player won't play them. I have no control over the remote server so can't change the mime type or file extensions. The files are legitimate mp4 files, if I copy one and change the extension they work fine.

Anybody got any idea how I can fool the ios video player into playing them?

Any help grateful appreciated I have been working on this for weeks and its driving me round the bend

Cheers
Toby

Comment: Can you use some type of server side proxy to change the extension on the fly?  So `myserver.com/myvid.mp4` actually sends back the stream?  Also; I'd check to be sure that the stream is a valid mp4. Could there be metadata or a file header or something similar that is missing?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The file is definatley valid, if you change the extension to mp4 it works fine. The server with the files on is a camera with an embeded web server , you connect the phone to it via wifi (so no web access at the same time) , which makes server side proxy impossible (I think)

Comment: A server side proxy is no different than any other server call; so it should work on wifi.

Comment: Thanks gives me another good avenue to look into (I'm new to flash builder / flex and ios programming) - if you know any resources with good examples of doing this kind of thing I woud really appreciate it. Cheers Toby

Comment: If I were building it in ColdFusion; I'd look into using something like CFContent: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_c_11.html .  Your server side proxy just has to retrieve the file; and send it back out.  I really hope I'm not sending you down a bad path.

Comment: Instead of loading the file directly, you could create a quick HTML page on the fly that loads the video using `<video>` tags and load the HTML page instead of the video in your StageWebView (assuming Safari will play the video when it is on a webpage, that is)